# Delegate Conversion C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert some C# code to VB .Net and am having issues with some of the delgate conversions.

BackupLibraries.cs

```
Public Class Backup
{
public event EventHandler<BackupPEventArgs> Backup;

...
if (BackupProgress != null) BackupProgress(this, new BackupProgressEventArgs(percent_complete))
...
}

public class BackupEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private float percentage;

        public BackupProgressEventArgs(float percentage)
        {
            this.percentage = percentage;
        }

        public float Percentage
        {
            get { return percentage; }
        }
    }
```

UnitTest.cs

```
public void BackupTest()
{
Backup bu = new Backup()
        bu.BackupProgress += delegate(object sender, Backup.BackupEventArgs e)

        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Percentage: " + e.Percentage.ToString());
        };
}
```

It's converting sb.Backup += delegate(object sender, SQLBackup.BackupProgressEventArgs e)
and wiring it to the event in the other class  I am having issues on.

In VB:

Backuplibraries.vb

```
Public Class Backup

Public Event Backup As EventHandler(Of BackupEventArgs)

...
RaiseEvent Backup(Me, New BackupEventArgs(percent_complete))
...
End Class

Public Class BackupEventArgs
            Inherits EventArgs
```

UnitTest.vb

```
Public Class BackupTest

Dim bu As New Backup()

bu.BackupProgress = Sub(sender As Object, e As BackupEventArgs)
                         Debug.WriteLine(e.Percentage.ToString())
                         End Sub

End Class
```

Of course

```
bu.BackupProgress = Sub(sender As Object, e As BackupEventArgs)
                             Debug.WriteLine(e.Percentage.ToString())
                             End Sub
```

is where the issue I am having with the conversion from C# to .Net is.

Comment: +1 Some related questions (`+=` -> `AddHandler`) but not exact duplicates due to the anonymous delegate in this question. They are probably duplicates of each other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636382/how-can-i-use-the-following-events-delgates-written-in-c-in-vb-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728926/how-to-convert-this-line-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net-windows-phone-7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492674/can-you-convert-this-to-vb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448323/how-do-i-translate-newbutton-click-delegate-window-isopen-false-in-vb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try AddHandler here

```
AddHandler bu.BackupProgress, AddressOf Sub(sender As Object, e As BackupEventArgs)
                         Debug.WriteLine(e.Percentage.ToString())
                         End Sub
```

To have the arguments come in, this would not be able to remain anonymous in this fashion in VB.Net. You would need to abstract out your method with a fixed address.

```
Protected Sub BackupProgressDelegate(sender as Object, e as BackupEventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Percentage.ToString())
End Sub

...

AddHandler bu.BackupProgress, AddressOf BackupProgressDelegate
```

Comment: Oh, you were faster. Deleted my answer since it was the same.

Comment: @DennisTraub: Speed at the cost of formatting I guess. Your answer was prettier :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `AddressOf` should not be here. It's needed for method groups (e.g. `AddressOf MyMethod`), not for lambdas.

Comment: @Heinzi: This is not a lambda, it's an anonymous delegate.

Comment: @Heinzi: Actually I stand corrected. Adding parameters to the anonymous delegate creates this as a lambda, and even in 4.0 the compiler does not like the anonymous delegate as written.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I created a new solution in 2010 and actually put the code in substituting button events for OPs custom events. The result ended up being that the compiler barked at me regarding the anonymous delegate as written. It also indicated that with arguments the compiler was analyzing it as a lambda expression. I was very sure I'd used the original syntax before, but can't remember the project and can't reproduce the results just now.

Comment: @Joel Weird. But either you made a mistake or this is a bug in the compiler, it’s unrelated to delegate-vs.-lambda and to presence or absence of arguments. The equivalent code works in C#. (`bu.BackupProgress += (sender, e) => {…}`).

Comment: @Joel No, it works [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763088.aspx) and [according to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9689097/1968)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's a great article, but I must be missing something in my solution because that example code also generates compile errors for me.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Are you sure? Your original solution without the `AddressOf` should work fine, and I actually use this syntax quite often. What compile error do you get? (PS: VB.NET does not support anonymous delegates, but it does support lambdas.)